# Find max value of tuple with multiple values being the same

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, and I need to find the tuple with the max value on the right side. I also need the program to print out each tuple that has this max value. I have tried using lambda, but that only returns one of the tuples with a max value on the left side. Specifically, I have tried:

```
max(TotalFriendsList,key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Which returns `(1,3)`

This is the list:

```
[(0, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 2),
 (5, 3),
 (6, 2),
 (7, 2),
 (8, 3),
 (9, 1)]
```

This is the output i need:

```
[(1,3),
(2,3),
(3,3),
(5,3),
(8,3)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This now, after optimization, goes through the list exactly once:

```
data = [(0, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 2),
 (5, 3),
 (6, 2),
 (7, 2),
 (8, 3),
 (9, 1)]

maxVal = -1
result = None

for datum in data:
    val = datum[1]
    if val > maxVal:
        result = [datum]
        maxVal = val
    elif val == maxVal:
        result.append(datum)

print result

print

# and the way he wanted it printed...
print "[" + ",\n".join([str(v) for v in result]) + "]"
```

Notice that since the first entry contains a "winning tuple", this code doesn't process the losers at all.  It just does a few comparisons for them, and comparisons cost almost nothing. So it basically does the bare minimum amount of work of building the result list in a single pass.  It wouldn't be so efficient if the first tuple weren't a winner.

Output:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (5, 3), (8, 3)]

[(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(3, 3),
(5, 3),
(8, 3)]
```

Only I did just what the guy asked for ;) (tic) - all answers were right on...good perpective on different ways to do the same problem

Comment: You probably don't want to assign a variable to `max`, shadowing the built-in.

Comment: Doesn't matter to me.  I don't use max(), and this is just a proof of concept.  For production code, you're absolutely right.  But for those that follow...I'll change it.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this fairly compact by getting the highest value, then getting corresponding tuples:

```
l = [(0, 2),
     (1, 3),
     (2, 3),
     (3, 3),
     (4, 2),
     (5, 3),
     (6, 2),
     (7, 2),
     (8, 3),
     (9, 1)]

# pass a generator expression to `max`
greatest = max(item[1] for item in l)

# "filter" `l`, keeping only tuples that have the greatest value as their second element
result = [item for item in l if item[1] == greatest]
print(result)
# [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (5, 3), (8, 3)]
```

Comment: Almost the same as @AkshayNevrekar - he splits out the second term of each tuple, while you keep the items intact. - for that reason, I think this one is a wee bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst = [(0, 2),
...  (1, 3),
...  (2, 3),
...  (3, 3),
...  (4, 2),
...  (5, 3),
...  (6, 2),
...  (7, 2),
...  (8, 3),
...  (9, 1)]
>>> mx = max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> filter(lambda x: x[1] == mx[1], lst)
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (5, 3), (8, 3)]
```